# How to create a multidimensional array to group by category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create an array that looks something like this, where my products are grouped my their category.

```
  [
    [
      name: category_1
        products: [
          [ name: product_1 ],
          [ name: product_2 ]
        ]
    ],
    [
      name: category_2
        products: [
          [ name: product_3 ],
          [ name: product_4 ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
```

Here is my code

```
public function getProducts() 
{
  $products = [];

  foreach(Category::all() as $category) 
  {
    $products = [
      'category' => $category->name
    ];

    foreach($category->product()->select['id', 'name']->get() as $product)
    {
      $products[$category->name][] = $product;
    }
  }

  return $products;
}
```

but my code doesn't give me the array that I need. I get

```
  [
    'category' => 'category_1'
    'category_1' => [
      0 => [
        'name' => 'product_1'
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

which I think is almost there, but I think I'm missing something, because they not grouped together and I'm only getting 1 item and
not all of it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get the same data from query builder by using `with()`

```
$products = Category:with('products:id,name')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: This kind of worked, but when I tried adding the column names, I didn't get the columns I wanted. I had to only put `products` in order to get the products that was attached to my category

Comment: Can you list out the columns which you want to include and from which model?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Laravel's `groupBy()`

```
Category::all()->groupBy('category');
```

This returns Laravel collection. If you need an array afterwards, you can use `toArray()`

```
Category::all()->groupBy('category')->toArray();
```